# How does Buchdahl's interior solution satisfy the Einstein field equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, stars

I was reading Schutz A First Course in General Relativity (2nd Edition) Section 10.6, where the Buchdahl exact solution was written down as follows:

For $Ar'\le\pi$,
$$
\exp(2\Phi) = (1-2\beta)(1-\beta-u)(1-\beta+u)^{-1}\\
\exp(2\Lambda) = (1-2\beta)(1-\beta-u)(1-\beta+u)^{-1}(1-\beta+\beta\cos{Ar'})^{-2}\\
p(r) = A^2(1-2\beta)u^2[8\pi(1-\beta+u)^2]^{-1}\\
\rho(r)=2A^2(1-2\beta)u(1-\beta-\frac32u)[8\pi(1-\beta+u)^2]^{-1}
$$
where $u=u(r')=\beta\frac{\sin(Ar')}{Ar'}$, where $\beta$ is an arbitrary constant and $A$ is a non-arbitrary constant, and $r'$ is defined implicitly in terms of r by
$$
r(r')=r'\frac{1-\beta+u}{1-2\beta} \tag1
$$

Schutz claimed that this solution satisfies the field equations, which are:
$$
\frac{dm}{dr}=4\pi r^2\rho\\
\frac{d\Phi}{dr}=\frac{m+4\pi r^3p}{r(r-2m)}\\
\frac{dp}{dr}=-(\rho+p)\frac{d\Phi}{dr}\\
$$
where $m=m(r)=\frac12 r(1-e^{-2\Lambda})$, $p=p(r)$ and $\rho=\rho(r)$.

I tried working out the field equations to express them explicitly in terms of $r'$. But even for the first equation, the attempt was in vain.

My attempt starts with finding the expression for $\frac{dr'}{dr}$ and $\frac{du}{dr'}$, which will be useful when doing chain rule for the equations.

From $(1)$, differentiating w.r.t $r$ gives
$$
1=(1-2\beta)^{-1}[\frac{dr'}{dr}(1-\beta+u)+r'\frac{du}{dr}]\\
\frac{dr'}{dr}=(1-2\beta)((1-\beta+\beta\cos(Ar'))^{-1}
$$
then by chain rule,
$$
\frac{du}{dr'}=\frac{\beta}{r'}[\cos{Ar'}-\frac{\sin{Ar'}}{Ar'}]
$$

Now I work out both sides for the first field equation. The RHS is simple:
$$
4\pi r^2\rho\\
=4\pi r'^2 (1-\beta+u)^2 (1-2\beta)^{-2} 2A^2 (1-2\beta) u (1-\beta-\frac32 u)[8\pi(1-\beta+u)^2]^{-1}\\
=A^2 \beta (1-2\beta)^{-2} r'^2 \frac{\sin(Ar')}{Ar'} (1-\beta-\frac32 \beta \frac{\sin(Ar')}{Ar'})
$$
The LHS is where I got stuck,
$$\frac{dm}{dr}=\frac{d}{dr} (\frac12 r(1-e^{-2\Lambda}))
\\=\frac12 [(1-e^{-2\Lambda})-r\frac{dr'}{dr}\frac{d}{dr'}(e^{-2\Lambda})]
\\ \text{... (some steps later)}
\\=\frac12 [1-(1-2\beta)^{-1} (1-\beta+\beta \frac{\sin Ar'}{Ar'})^{-1} (1-\beta-\beta \frac{\sin Ar'}{Ar'}) (1-\beta+\beta \cos Ar')^2\\+2\beta (1-\beta) (1-2\beta)^{-1} (\cos Ar' -\frac{\sin Ar'}{Ar'}) (1-\beta-\beta \frac{\sin Ar'}{Ar'})^{-1} (1-\beta+\beta \cos Ar') \\ +2A\beta (1-2\beta)^{-1} r'\sin Ar' (1-\beta-\beta \frac{\sin Ar'}{Ar'})]
$$
which looks no way close to the RHS. Could anyone give some advice?